# The lowest weight of a representation is $w_0 \lambda$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

There is the well-known fact that if $\lambda$ is the highest weight of $V$ a finite-dimensional irreducible $\mathfrak{g}$-module, then $w_0 \lambda$ is the lowest weight (here $\mathfrak{g}$ is any complex semisimple Lie algebra), where $w_0$ is the longest element of the Weyl group.
**Why is this true?**

Related questions have been asked on MSE, but not answering why, only giving the statement.
It has almost been answered in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111127/finding-highest-weight-of-dual-of-a-representation-of-a-semisimple-lie-algebra) but not concretely for me.

Specifically, this is the proof I am reading:

> The set of weights of $V$, denote by $\chi(V)$, are invariant under the Weyl group action.
> Let $Q_+$ be the semigroup generated by $\Phi^+$.
> Since $w_0 \cdot Q_+ = -Q_+$, **we have $w_0 (\lambda) \prec \mu$ for all $\mu \in \chi(V)$**, which implies the assertion.

Why is the bolded statement correct? I'm not even sure it is, just graphically looking at the picture of the weights of the representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ with highest weight $\lambda = \varpi_1 + 2 \varpi_2$ below.

[image]

The weight marked with the open circle at $2\pi/3$ representing $s_2 s_1 (\lambda - \alpha_2)$ does not graphically appear to be a higher weight than $w_0(\lambda)$.
What am I misunderstanding here/how do I reason the above statement algebraically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a picture says more than words here.

[image]

If $x = s_2 s_1(\lambda - \alpha_2)$, then the green region contains all weights which are $\preceq x$. The green region is the region $x - \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\alpha_1 - \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\alpha_2$: every point that can be written as $x$ plus some strictly negative linear combination of simple roots, or equivalently $x$ plus some strictly negative linear combination of simple roots. (Beware: this order is usually defined by $y \preceq x$ if and only if $y \in x - \mathbb{N}\alpha_1 - \mathbb{N} \alpha_2$, so even though it looks like $0 \preceq \lambda$ from the region-description, actually $0$ and $\lambda$ are incomparable).

Algebraically, we have that $y \preceq x$ if and only if $y + q = x$ for some $x \in Q^+$. Applying $w_0$ to both sides gives that $w_0 y = -w_0 q + w_0 x$, and since $- w_0 q \in Q^+$ we have $w_0 x \preceq w_0 y$.

Comment: The geometric argument makes sense (although you seem to repeat yourself?). I am a little confused by the second paragraph though - $w_0x \preceq w_0y$, but why does this show that $w_0\lambda$ is the lowest weight?

Comment: @mizh: if a set has a maximal element under a partial order, and then you apply a map which reverses the order of each pair, then the element that used to be maximal gets sent to a minimal element. So all we need to know is that the map $\lambda \mapsto w_0 \lambda$ is order-reversing.